# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'write')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey guys I have a problem.
I'm trying to open a project made in Angular 5.2.0 and its Angular/cli version is 1.7.4, my Angular/cli version is 14.0.7...
I executed "npm install" and it doesn't give me any error, but when I write "ng version" to see the local version of angular, it gave me an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'write')", I tried to execute "ng serve --open" and doesn't work neither.

The steps I followed and their results were:
1.- npm install --> ok;
2.- ng version (to check if the Angular's package local version was installed) --> Error = "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'write')";
3.- ng serve --open (to try open the app) --> Error = same as above.

Comment: My final goal is to update the application to newer angular version

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Please review the guidelines for [ask] and try to provide a [mre] so that others can demonstrate your issue for themselves.

Answer (score 4):

This error message is not helpful at all.  It turns out it may be a wrong angular version.

Try downgrading to version 14.0.0.

```
npm -g i @angular/cli@14.0.0
```

In my case, I discovered downgrading to any version 14 or below seemed to work, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: This helped me to make progress, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please recreate incrementally with Angular v14.